# How can I use regex in a migration query condition?

Tags: 8, database, migrations

I have data in a table that looks like this:

```
|-------------------------------------------------------|
|ID|              Data                                  |
|--|----------------------------------------------------|
| 1|{"key":"value",...,"image":"1234567",..."key:value"}|
| 2|{"key":"value",...,"image":"",..."key:value"}       |
| 3|{"key":"value",...,"image":"9876543",..."key:value"}|
```

In my migration I only want to import items that have an image ID in the Data column.

Previously I was doing this in my migration class query() method:

```
class myMigration extends SqlBase {

  public function query() {
    return $this->select('data_table', 'd')
      ->distinct()
      ->fields('d', ['ID', 'Data'])
      ->condition('Data', '%' . db_like('"image":') . '%', 'LIKE');
  }

  public function fields() {

    $fields = [
      'ID' => t('ID'),
    ];

    return $fields;
  }

  public function getIds() {
    return [
      'ID' => [
        'type' => 'string',
      ],
    ];
  }
```

This was also selecting rows where the image value was empty in the Data column.

This query in SQL works for selecting the correct data, but I cannot get it to work with the query() method in my migration:

```
SELECT ID, Data    
FROM data_table
WHERE Data REGEXP '"image":"\d*[^>"]';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to use `REGEXP` operator in a normal `condition()` method, although it is not stated in [the documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/conditional-clauses).

The answer was found on [this example.](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!tests!Drupal!KernelTests!Core!Database!SelectTest.php/function/SelectTest%3A%3AtestRegexCondition/8.2.x)

Solution:

```
  public function query() {
    return $this->select('data_table', 'd')
      ->distinct()
      ->fields('d', ['ID', 'Data'])
      ->condition('Data', '"image":"\d*[^>"]', 'REGEXP');
  }
```

Comment: The documentation wasn't necessarily wrong, but it wasn't very explicit; I've added a sentence calling out `REGEXP` as an example of a database-specific operator that will be passed through.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the `where()` method:

```
return $this->select('data_table', 'd')
    ->distinct()
    ->fields('d', ['ID', 'Data'])
    ->where('Data REGEXP \'"image":"\d*[^>"]\'');
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use SqlBase Class and do yourself the query. Your Class can extends SourcePluginBase.

```
  use Drupal\Core\Database\Database;

  $database = Database::getConnection('default', $your_database_key_in_settings_php);
  $query = $database->query($sql_query);
  $data = $query->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```